# C++ Is it possible to define a implicit conversion from pair<int, int> to pair<float,float>?

Tags: c++, templates, grammar

```
template<typename type>
using point = std::pair<type, type>;

template<typename type>
point<type> operator-(point<type> a, point<type> b)
{
    return{ a.first - b.first, a.second - b.second };
}

int main() {
    point<float> a = { 0, 0 };
    point<int> b = { 1, 2 };
    point<float> p = a - b; // This does not compile.       
    return 0;
}
```

How can I pass a point float and a point int argument to my "-" operator ,and implicit convert the point int argument to point float type ?

Sure, I can declare the point as a class ,and use a constructor to achieve this. But that seems quite verbose to me .

Comment: What is the problem? http://ideone.com/zJlR94

Comment: `point` (`pair`) does not contain any `x` and `y` members. Also, you're not doing anything with the template parameter `type`: `operator-<void>` still takes two `point<float>`s and returns a `point<float>`. Taking out the unused `template<typename type>` line and fixing `x` and `y` to `first` and `second` makes your code work. Show some concrete minimal failing code that doesn't contain a bunch of unrelated errors that demonstrates what you want to ask.

Comment: @iouvxz Your method dist is not used and should be removed to make the exemple minimal. And .x and .y don't exist so you should use .first and .second (more generally, really compile the example you use in your question to be sure it's valid)

Comment: @iouvxz Thanks for fixing the errors. However, you shouldn't edit the question to remove the initial issue (by adding the explicit conversion) otherwise it becomes hard to understand the question and the answers ... Moreover, I think what you want is something that works without having to explicitely convert your points.

Comment: @Colin Pitrat Yes ,but if I use a point<type> template ,and pass a point<int> argument and a point<float> argument to the "-" operator ,implicit conversion would be ambiguous .

Comment: In the solution I proposed, you have the "natural" conversion that you have with the underlying type, so `point<int>-point<float>` would result in a `point<float>` returned.

Comment: @iouvxz I have edited your code to show the actual problem, removing unnecessary lines and leaving the compiler problem that you were originally facing. Personally I think it is a cleaner fit for the Q&A format of SO this way, if you have serious objections feel free to rollback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** Originally the question did not mention the `operator-` and just asked if it is possible to automatically convert a `point<int>` to `point<float>` without making it a class. My answer addresses that question. I will leave it for reference. [Colin Pitrat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35915590/2920343)'s answer solves the problem as it is currently formulated better.

---

It is already defined for you: `std::pair` has a *generalized copy constructor* (i.e. a constructor allowing implicit conversion between convertible template parameters)

```
template< class U1, class U2 >
pair( const pair<U1, U2>& p );
```

(which is `constexpr` as of C++14) which allows initializing a `pair<T1, U1>` with a `pair<T2, U2>` as long as `T2` is implicitly convertible to `T1` and `U2` to `U1`:

> 4) Initializes `first` with `p.first` and `second` with `p.second`.
>   ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair))

This means that the following code runs fine:

```
template<typename type> 
using point = std::pair<type, type>;

float dist(point<float> a, point<float> b)
{
    return pow(pow(a.first-b.first, 2) + pow(a.second - b.second, 2), 0.5);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << dist(point<int>{ 0, 0 }, point<int>{ 1, 1 });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This kind of constructor, allowing implicit conversion between convertible template parameters, is called a `generalized copy constructor`

Comment: Thanks @ColinPitrat, added that to the answer.

Comment: True @ColinPitrat, the question was edited later. You have already written an excellent answer now so I will leave my answer-as is.